# Javascript/jquery confirmation on pre image loads of variable's div images before writing them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript/jquery variable like this:

```
var divs='<div><img src="link1"></div><div><img src="link2"></div><div><img src="link3"></div>'
```

Finally I am inserting these `div`s to my container using some other jquery library. But I want to load those images before inserting them to the container.

Since I want it to check even before appending, so jquery `.load` will not work here.

```
$('.img')
    .load(function(){
        $('#result1').text('Image is loaded!'); 
    })
    .error(function(){
        $('#result1').text('Image is not loaded!');
    });
```

So what are the other choices do I have?

Comment: What does `$('.img')` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [onImagesLoad plugin.](http://www.cirkuit.net/projects/jquery/onImagesLoad/)

Answer (score 0):

You shoult try:

```
$('img')
    .load(function(){
        $('#result1').text('Image is loaded!'); 
    })
    .error(function(){
        $('#result1').text('Image is not loaded!');
    });
```

`$('.img')` selector all element has class which name is: 'img'.

`$('img')` selector all `<img> </img>` element

Answer (score 0):

Pre-load the image some where in the page and make it hidden.now it loads instantly without delay ....

snippet-EX:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- your code -->

<img src="link1" style="visibility:hidden"/>
</body>
</html>
```